How does a Space-Stabilized Inertial Navigation System actually torque its gimbals?
I've been trying to make a fairly-accurate video (with 3D animations coming soon) about Inertial Navigation Systems (INS), in which I plan to cover all the details from each gyroscopes and accelerometers along with their working principles, up to how the whole system actually worked (the state-space integration, error functions etc.) And so I went on to get some references from books, journals, research reports and occasionally, other explanatory videos about INS.
It was all going well until up to three-quarters of my project, I just realized "how exactly does a space-stabilized INS, actually stabilize?" NB: space-stabilized INS means that the gyro and accelerometer triads' orientation are kept stable with respect to inertial frame.
Because of all the topics that I've make a summary on, from the gyros (displacement gyro, rate gyro, rate-integrating gyro) and the gimbals (torquer motors, resolver or synchros), I still didn't find any deep explanation on how a space-stabilization mechanism actually works. All that I've got is from the book Fundamentals Of High Accuracy Inertial Navigation by Andrew A. Chatfield, and the book Inertial Navigation Systems Analysis by Kenneth R. Britting.

Since the space-stabilized system instruments an inertially nonrotating
coordinate system the gyros are nominally untorqued. ...Ideally the compensation commands cancel with the deterministic drift
and the platform is nonrotating relative to the inertial frame. Thus the
commanded platform angular velocity is equal to the desired platform
angular velocity which is equal to zero; $$ \omega_c^g = \omega_{ip}^p = 0 $$ where $ \omega_c^g $ specifies the commanded rotation rate, and $ \omega_{ip}^i $ being the desired angular velocity of platform. [Britting, Kenneth R. (1971)]


For stabilization to an ECI coordinate system, the platform remains untorqued
except for calibration torques. Thus, $$ \omega_c^p = \delta\omega_{cal}^p $$ [Chatfield, Andrew A. (1997)]. $ \omega_c^p $ denotes stable platform commanded rate, and $ \delta\omega_{cal}^p $ denotes small calibration rate.

As far as I've accomplished, my understanding is that if the gyro triad's sensed rotation rate can be described as a single rotation through an axes. And because that rotation is sensed on a supposed-to-be-inertial frame, i.e. the platform frame; then there must be an equal and opposite commanded rotation rate, that would nullify such sensed rotation rate.
I've tried resolving the sensed rotation rate to each gimbal's rotation basis vector (the respective axes in which gimbals may rotate relative to each other), both by viewing the rotatoin rate from platform frame and body frame. And I'm currently stuck at what kind of methods can actually stabilize this gyro triad.

Have you seen this: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19650024833 ? It describes in detail how the Apollo inertial platform worked, including the torquing.

@OrganicMarble based on the paper you cited, it seems the gimbals are basically mounted on servos, which do double duty for both detecting the angle change and also driving the gimbal frames directly

@OrganicMarble I've just read that report, but I still didn't find the exact way of transforming the gyro rate inputs into gimbal angle outputs, be it in the form of equations or a control loop. Or am I missing something?
